# Java Enumerated Types Error

Tags: java, enums, subclass

so I have a base class where I define an enum variable with this block of code.

```
    enum Faction {
            AMITY, ABNIGATION, DAUNTLESS, EURIDITE, CANDOR
        };
```

And I'm trying to test to see if everything in my subclass works by using a driver. My constructor in my subclass looks like this.

```
public Dauntless(String f, String l, int a,  int ag, int end, Faction d) {
        super(f, l, a, d);
        if (ag >= 0 && ag <= 10) {
            this.agility = ag;
        } else {
            this.agility = 0;
        }
        if (end >= 0 && end <= 10) {
            this.endurance = end;
        } else {
            this.endurance = 0;
        }
    }
```

And my driver looks like this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Faction this = Faction.DAUNTLESS;
        Dauntless joe = new Dauntless("Joseph", "Hooper", 20, 5, 3, this);
        Dauntless vik = new Dauntless("Victoria", "Ward", 19, 6, 2, this);
        Dauntless winner;
        winner = joe.battle(vik);
        System.out.println(winner);


}
```

It keeps saying that `Faction this = Faction.DAUNTLESS;`is not a statement. Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: `this` is a keyword in Java.

Comment: `subclass` of **what**???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `this` is a keyword in Java, used for things like:

```
this.faction;
```

You can't use keywords as variable names. Just change the variable name:

```
Faction this_faction = Faction.DAUNTLESS;
```

Then, of course, you need to change references to the variable:

```
Dauntless joe = new Dauntless("Joseph", "Hooper", 20, 5, 3, this_faction);
Dauntless vik = new Dauntless("Victoria", "Ward", 19, 6, 2, this_faction);
```

Comment: I should've figured that out. I made the changes and now i'm getting. Cannot find symbol for Faction. Did i define my enums wrong?