# Can't use enum in Java (Error:Can't find symbol)

Tags: java, enums, subclass

So I have a class file with just my enums that looks like this

```
public class FactionNames {
    public enum Faction {AMITY, ABNEGATION, DAUNTLESS, ERUDITE, CANDOR};
}
```

I have a class that uses these enums in a constructor which looks like this

```
public Dauntless(String f, String l, int a,  int ag, int end, Faction d) {
        super(f, l, a, d);
        if (ag >= 0 && ag <= 10) {
            this.agility = ag;
        } else {
            this.agility = 0;
        }
        if (end >= 0 && end <= 10) {
            this.endurance = end;
        } else {
            this.endurance = 0;
        }
    }
```

So to make sure everything in this class works properly I want to create some Dauntless objects in a driver, but I keep getting these errors

```
D:\Documents\Google Drive\Homework\1331
Test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Faction test;
        ^
  symbol:   class Faction
  location: class Test
Test.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        test = Faction.DAUNTLESS;
               ^
  symbol:   variable Faction
  location: class Test
2 errors
```

I'm using my driver which looks like this. Is there anything wrong with my syntax? I can't figure out why i'm getting this errors.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Faction test; 
        test = Faction.DAUNTLESS;
        Dauntless joe = new Dauntless("Joseph", "Hooper", 20, 5, 3, test);
        Dauntless vik = new Dauntless("Victoria", "Ward", 19, 6, 2, test);
        Dauntless winner;
        winner = joe.battle(vik);
        System.out.println(winner);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do your `import` statements look like?

Comment: i don't have any import statements. They're all in the same directory should'nt the files be able to see each other.

Comment: Just for the record: [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844637/java-enumerated-types-error).

Comment: Whic java version you are using. Before java 5 Enum was not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `enum` type `Faction` is nested within the top level class `FactionNames`.

```
public class FactionNames {
    public enum Faction {AMITY, ABNEGATION, DAUNTLESS, ERUDITE, CANDOR};
}
```

If you want to use its simple name, you'll need to import it

```
import com.example.FactionNames.Faction;
```

Alternatively, you can use its qualified name

```
FactionNames.Faction test = FactionNames.Faction.DAUNTLESS;
```

Comment: So I have several classes that are connected that implement the Faction enum. So do I have to go back and import it in every class I want to use it in?

Comment: @Josephhooper Either that or refactor your `enum` type by extracting it to its own `.java` file within the same package as all your other classes.

Comment: Wait since all the classes are in the same folder doesn't that mean they should all be in the same package?

Comment: @Josephhooper Not necessarily. The package is declared with a `package` declaration at the top of the source file.